# Undesired parallel execution of Laravel IronMq Queues

Tags: php, laravel, queue, ironmq

I am trying to set an IronMq queue with Laravel, and I have it working already, but the point is that the behavior is not the desired one.

I expect IronMq to wait until a job is complete ($job->delete()) to push a new one, but I found out that it pushes messages before the previous one is finished.

The code is structured as follows:

```
Route::post('queue/send' ,function() 
{
    ...
    Queue::push(function($job) use ($data)
    {
        ...
        $job->delete();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Has anyone found out the way to prevent the parallel behavior and make it sequential?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, I decided to use Beanstalkd instead of IronMQ.

It's much messier, but it provides with the desired functionality and I am not depending on no one.

Answer (score 2):

Push queues will naturally continue to push messages regardless of whether or not the job is done as they are 2 independent systems. Secondly, the purpose of utilizing a push queue is for it to be as realtime as possible.

IronMQ specifically [has retries](http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/push_queues/#retries) which, as it sounds, will retry pushing the message to the desired endpoint X number of times(which you set) in designated intervals (which you set) - hopefully this will help solve your problems.

If you desire that a job only be processed once the previous has been completed, and a slight delay is acceptable, then I'd recommend polling the queue and retrieving in batches.

Comment: I guess that polling the queue or using Iron Worker is the way to go, but I can't understand how a queue system does not have the option of having a single process at a time....
The retry is not a solution as the process is well treated, but have some concurrency issues.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Unlike delayed job or an in-app queuing system, a push queue has no knowledge of when the job is done on the server side. The two are independent systems.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could try to use IronMQ class instead of laravel Queue class:

```
$ironmq = new \IronMQ(array(
    'token' => Config::get('queue.connections.iron.token', 'xxx'),
    'project_id' => Config::get('queue.connections.iron.project', 'xxx')
));
$ironmq->postMessage($queue_name, "Hello world");
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between Laravel and IronMq queues as I set the driver to IronMq in the config/queue.php file.
How does it solves the concurrency problem?